# Extract string with whitespace inside Perl Regex

Tags: regex, string, perl, extract

I have some troubles trying to get arguments after equal sign, but argument can include string in quotes with spaces inside I cannot figure out how to get arguments separated by space including spaces if quotes are specified.

```
name=MyName lastname='John Black' fathername='Bill Gen' age=30
```

The result should be following

```
         %result = ( 'name' = > 'MyName',
                     'lastname' => 'John Black',
                      'fathername' => 'Bill Gen',
                      'age' => 30);
```

Also I need to omit quotes in result hash.
I have tried following regex, but it doesn't include arguments with space inside.

```
((?:\w+=)([^\s]+)\s)+
```

How to build regex correctly to include spaces inside string if this string is in the quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it could be a job for [`Text::ParseWords`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::ParseWords). You can provide it with a regex for the delimiters (space and equalsign `[ =]`), and it will split your string, while respecting quoted strings. It will also allow for escaped quotes.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Text::ParseWords;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my %data = quotewords('[ =]', 0, $_);
    print Dumper \%data;
}

__DATA__
name=MyName lastname='John Black' fathername='Bill Gen' age=30
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'name' => 'MyName',
          'lastname' => 'John Black',
          'age' => '30',
          'fathername' => 'Bill Gen'
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=['"]*\K[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+
```

Simply use this and get the matches.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iS6jF6/8